# What should I use to perform similarity functions on 200 column 12 million row dataset?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bigdata, similarity

**Problem:** 
I have a huge table of feature vectors. Each element in a vector is composed of two INTEGERs. Here's an example:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KEY |  VALUE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | f1    | f2    | f3    | f4    | f5       | f6       | f7    |  f8   | f9
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 13 42 |       | 546 43| 43 24 | 435  634 |          | 45  43|  4  5 | 5 647
 2  | 24 32 | 54 35 |       |       | 3124 32  | 454 3    | 4   5 |  12 1 |   
 3  | 3  1  | 54 32 |       | 43 24 |          | 31  2432 | 454 3 |  4  5 | 1 21    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Suppose I have about 12 million rows with unique keys and about 200 columns (=400 subcolumns). Values in random columns, as you can see, may be missing if that element doesn't have that feature.

I want to query row X (not present in the table) against the table to find the top N (N = 10-20 maybe) best matches, using some custom-made similarity function f(vector1, vector2) that will do == checks and return a similarity score considering different weights for matching of different columns.

**Question:**
What kind of implementation do you think would be best for this, speaking in terms of NoSQL databases? I want to make real-time queries. I'm thinking about using HBase with Hadoop (Or MongoDB with Hadoop, which one would be better?) and write a MapReduce job to execute the similarity function on every row and get the results. I'm apprehensive of whether the batch-processing workhorse that Hadoop is would provide me with good real-time performance (max. 2 seconds). I don't have much experience with Lucene - will that come of any use here?

Apart of this, any idea on how I can avoid making full table MapReduce scans and optimize it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting suggestions from a couple of friends, I looked up the documentation on ElasticSearch. Seems like that's the perfect tool for my use-case. It's built for search/retrieval needs such as this, shards like anything, can handle huge data. Here's what should be done:

Store each row in a document, with the key elements being the _id field and each f1, f2... field as different fields. One can use the [boost fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/boost-field/) feature to increase relevance of certain fields (basically assigning more weights to them, essentially eliminating the need for my similarity function). This can even be done during [query time](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/field-query/), hence letting the user assign weights depending upon the use-case.

Here's an example query than might work for this use-case (untested):

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
        "and" : [
         {      
              "query" : {
                    "bool" : {
                         "should" : [
                              { "match" : { "f192" : { "boost" : 2,"query" : "232"} } },
                              { "match" : { "f16" : { "boost" : 1,"query" : "4324"} } },
                              { "match" : { "f25" : { "boost" : 0.2,"query" : "76783"} } },
                         ]
                    }
                }
         },
         {
              "exists" : { "field" : "f67" }
         }
       ]
    }
  }
}'
```